# How do I form characters design with do loop

Tags: fortran, do-loops

I am trying to make characters with an output as such in Fortran but I don't know how to. I made one with columns of asterisks but now I need it to change to the image linked.
I am a novice at Fortran.

[image: screenshot from given example]

Here's my code for the columns:

```
program chardesign

    integer complete
    do complete = 1, 5
        write (*, 10, advance='no')
10      format ('  *  ')
    enddo
    !Newline to complete
    write (*, 10)
    stop

end program chardesign
```

How can I go about this?

Comment: What do you want to achieve with  `format (' * ')`? Is this a homework? Even if yes, do notnlearn the format statement (use format strings) and putting the stop before the end (it is useless or even harmful).

Comment: You need a do loop iteration for each line and you need to use the iteration variable to print the line correctly. Telling you how exactly would not help ypur learning process (whether at school or in private).

Answer (score 1):

Since we can no longer restrain ourselves from offering solutions...

Suppose we had a file called `diamond.txt` that had the picture already drawn:

```
    *    
   ***   
  *****  
 ******* 
*********
 ******* 
  *****  
   ***   
    *
```

I know it's not visible here, but each line in `diamond.txt` has sufficient trailing spaces to make it 9 characters long. Now we just need a program that copies `diamond.txt` to its output:

```
program diamond
   implicit none
   character(9) line
   open(10,file='diamond.txt',status='old')
   do
      read(10,'(a)',end=20) line
      write(*,'(a)') line
   end do
20 continue
end program diamond
```

The program has a couple of new features: first off it has `implicit none` which forces the programmer to declare all variables, thus avoiding a common source of hard-to-trace programming errors. Then it declares a character variable `character(9) line` which creates a variable which always contains 9 characters. There are rules that govern what happens if you try to assign it to a string of lesser or greater length, but we won't do that here.

Then it opens the file `diamond.txt`. The unit number, 10, will be used to reference the file in subsequent I/O statements. The `status='old'` part will cause the program to abort if it can't find `diamond.txt`.
Then we have a `do` statement which means `do forever`. Of course we don't really want to 'do forever', so there should be some way to exit the loop from its body.

Now we have a `read` statement that reads from unit 10, which, due to our previous `open` statement, is our file `diamond.txt`. The `end=20` part means that when the `read` statement tries to read past end-of-file execution jumps to statement number 20, which gets us out of the loop. The format `(a)` does character I/O. It is the same as `(a9)` because the program knows that the length of the character variable to be read, `line`, is 9, so it will try to read the next 9 characters from `diamond.txt` and put them in variable `line`. After the `read` statement is complete, the file pointer advances to the next line of `diamond.txt`.

Then the `write` statement just writes variable `line` to standard output, thus copying the current line of `diamond.txt` to the screen.
When it's done, the `end=20` branch is taken getting us to the `20 continue` statement after which the `end` line is encountered and execution terminates.

So how could we do this without an external file? We could just convert the picture into a `format` statement and then print according to the `format`:

```
1 format('    *    '/ &
         '   ***   '/ &
         '  *****  '/ &
         ' ******* '/ &
         '*********'/ &
         ' ******* '/ &
         '  *****  '/ &
         '   ***   '/ &
         '    *    ')
print 1
end
```

So we have encountered a new format specifier, `/`, the 'slash', which advances I/O to the next record (or line). Also the free-format continuation character `&`, the 'ampersand', which means that the current line continues to the next noncomment line. Also the `print` statement where here `print 1` has the same effect as `write(*,1)`.

OK, but what if we wanted to carry out some kind of calculation to produce the picture? If we considered the picture to lie on a raster array where row i ran from 1 at the top to 9 at the bottom and column j ran from column 1 at the left to column 9 at the right, we might observe that the image is symmetric about i=5 and about j=5. If we considered i and j to run from -4 to 4 instead we might be able to see some patterns that enable us to take advantage of the symmetry now about the y-axis and x-axis. Accordingly we write a program that will print out the coordinates...

```
print"(9(1x:'(',i2,',',i2,')'))",[((i,j,j=-4,4),i=-4,4)];end
```

Now we have a couple of new program elements: there is an array constructor `[stuff]` which will create an array of the elements listed within the square brackets.
`[(more_stuff,i=-4,4)]` is an *ac-implied-do* which effectively creates a list by evaluating `more_stuff` sequentially for each value of `i` from -4 to 4, thus a list of 9 things.
`[((still_more_stuff,j=-4,4),i=-4,4)]` is a nested *ac-impied-do* which for each value of `i` makes a list by evaluating `still_more_stuff` sequentially for each value of `j` from -4 to 4, thus there is a list of 9*9=81 things.
Since `still_more_stuff` is `i,j`, i.e. 2 things, the array constructor creates an array of 162 things, each `(i,j)` pair with `j` varying faster than `I`.

The `print` statement has a format string surrounded by `"` double quotes rather than `'` apostrophes so that we can use apostrophe-delimited strings in the format.
The `9(stuff)` part is a repeat count that means to do the formats specified in `stuff` 9 times over.
The `1x` format says just skip one space and the following colon just separates it from the next format item. We can use `,` (comma), `:` (colon), or `/` (slash) to separate format items. As the reader will recall, slash skips to the next record; for the purposes or the current discussion let's ignore the distinction between comma and colon.

The `i2` format prints out an integer in a field of width 2. If it takes more than 2 characters to print out the integer it will print out two asterisks `**` instead.
So the format with the repeat count will print out 2*9=18 integers. When the format is exhausted there are rules called format reversion that in this case will result in output advancing to the next line and the format being reused.

Finally, in free format code one can write the next line of code on the current one if the current statement is followed by a semicolon `;`. Thus `;end` puts the required `end` statement at the end of the program. Note that the introductory `program` statement, although good style, is optional.

The output of the program is as follows:

```
 (-4,-4) (-4,-3) (-4,-2) (-4,-1) (-4, 0) (-4, 1) (-4, 2) (-4, 3) (-4, 4)
 (-3,-4) (-3,-3) (-3,-2) (-3,-1) (-3, 0) (-3, 1) (-3, 2) (-3, 3) (-3, 4)
 (-2,-4) (-2,-3) (-2,-2) (-2,-1) (-2, 0) (-2, 1) (-2, 2) (-2, 3) (-2, 4)
 (-1,-4) (-1,-3) (-1,-2) (-1,-1) (-1, 0) (-1, 1) (-1, 2) (-1, 3) (-1, 4)
 ( 0,-4) ( 0,-3) ( 0,-2) ( 0,-1) ( 0, 0) ( 0, 1) ( 0, 2) ( 0, 3) ( 0, 4)
 ( 1,-4) ( 1,-3) ( 1,-2) ( 1,-1) ( 1, 0) ( 1, 1) ( 1, 2) ( 1, 3) ( 1, 4)
 ( 2,-4) ( 2,-3) ( 2,-2) ( 2,-1) ( 2, 0) ( 2, 1) ( 2, 2) ( 2, 3) ( 2, 4)
 ( 3,-4) ( 3,-3) ( 3,-2) ( 3,-1) ( 3, 0) ( 3, 1) ( 3, 2) ( 3, 3) ( 3, 4)
 ( 4,-4) ( 4,-3) ( 4,-2) ( 4,-1) ( 4, 0) ( 4, 1) ( 4, 2) ( 4, 3) ( 4, 4)
```

Looking at these results we might observe that within the diamond, |i|+|j|<=4 while outside, |i|+|j|>=5. Let's create a program to check this:

```
print'(9(L1))',[((abs(j)+abs(i)<5,j=-4,4),i=-4,4)];end
```

Similar to the last program, but now the `still_more_stuff` in the inner *ac-implied-do*, `abs(j)+abs(i)<5` is a `logical` expression which asks *'is |j|+|i| less than 5?'* The value of the expression will be `.TRUE.` or `.FALSE.`, depending on the outcome of this test.
The `L1` format is a `logical` I/O specifier that outputs `T` for .TRUE. or `F` for .FALSE..

Output of the program is as follows:

```
FFFFTFFFF
FFFTTTFFF
FFTTTTTFF
FTTTTTTTF
TTTTTTTTT
FTTTTTTTF
FFTTTTTFF
FFFTTTFFF
FFFFTFFFF
```

We can see the diamond but we need to convert to  (spaces) and `*` (asterisks):

```
print'(9a)',merge('*',' ',[((abs(j)+abs(i)<5,j=-4,4),i=-4,4)]);end
```

And this does it! The `merge` function processes our `logical` array (the third argument) and everywhere a `.TRUE.` element is encountered, replaces it with an asterisk `*` (the first argument) while every `.FALSE.` element is replaced by a space  (the second argument).

The resulting 81-element character array is printed out 9 elements at a time by the `(9a)` format string, resulting in the desired output. The whole program, although complex to write, was only 66 characters long :)

Comment: Nice work. I would preferably do instead `print'(9a)',((merge('*',' ',(abs(j)+abs(i)<5)),j=-4,4),i=-4,4);end` to avoid iterating twice (once for the array creation and again for the printing).

Comment: @RodrigoRodrigues thanks for taking the time to pick through and edit my post. I agree that your changes clarify my intent. You can see how hard it was to restrain myself from posting these solutions. I didn't even post the one that read into a Hollerith format. I was trying to teach the questioner how to do good, not evil :) I see that you replaced my *ac-implied-do* with an *io-implied-do* reducing its length down to 64 characters. Very nice!

Answer (score 0):

I propose this approach on implementation, because it gives you flexibility on the character string length to be printed.

```
program chardesign
  implicit none

  call print_diamond('*', 5, 1)
  call print_diamond('()', 3, 3)
  call print_diamond('.', 1, 4)
  call print_diamond('0', 0, 3)

contains

  subroutine print_diamond(str, depth, start)
    character(*), intent(in) :: str
    integer, intent(in) :: depth, start
    character(len(str)) :: spc
    integer :: i, span

    spc = ''
    span = start + (depth - 1) * 2
    print '(a)', (repeat(spc, (span - i) / 2) // repeat(str, i), i = start, span, 2)
    print '(a)', (repeat(spc, (span - i) / 2) // repeat(str, i), i = span - 2, start, -2)
  end
end
```

This yields the following output:

```
    *
   ***
  *****
 *******
*********
 *******
  *****
   ***
    *

    ()()()
  ()()()()()
()()()()()()()
  ()()()()()
    ()()()

....
```

Comment: The upside is that if the assignment says do it with a do loop, the student won't understand this and will fail when asked about the meaning.

Comment: I didn't know it was a homework; I though OP actually needed this for some project: Then I remembered I once wrote this code for a number puzzle and decided to share (it had hexagonal shape, but almost the same thing).